# How to download a subset of the reports based on a specific indication of query term?

Tags: openfda, download

I understand that for performance purposes in my case it will be better to download the data rather than accessing it through the public API. On a practical note I am only interested in a subset of the FAERS reports, for example, only those reports that have Alzheimers disease as an indication or key word. Is that possible.

How can I download a subset of the reports based on a specific indication of query term?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, openFDA does not currently offer a capability to produce "filtered" downloads. Your best bet would be downloading the entire dataset and then processing JSON locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not understanding your requirements correctly...?

Why can you not search for your dataset via the API and use the response that is returned as your "filtered" download?

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=:"Alzheimers"](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=:%22Alzheimers%22)

-Michelle